How to trigger a flow if list item fields are updated and not its attachment
I have one automated workflow which triggers whenever an item gets modified in list and it resets status of item from Approved to New whenever user edits the item. The issue is that even if users are not editing the item and just opens the attachment to that item, then also SharePoint is creating a new version in that list item and workflow resets the status.
I want that workflow should only trigger if item fields are updated and not the attachment. How can i achieve that?


Currently, flow will trigger when an item is created or modified including the attachment update.
It's not possible to trigger a flow when list item fields are updated and except its attachment.
If you would like this feature to be added in Microsoft Flow, please submit an idea to Flow Ideas Forum:
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Flow-Ideas/idb-p/FlowIdeas

One way is the action "Get changes for an item or a file (properties only)" to either cancel or proceed with your flow.
The flow will still trigger anytime the item is modified (add/remove attachments + column changes though.
With the "Get changes for an item or a file (properties only)" you could cancel the flow if not column was changed, indicating that is was an attachment change, but also have more control when specific columns change.

Only "Modified" column has changed



"Choice" column has changed



List of available columns in the list


